# Not getting tree with expected link style in ReactJS using D3

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm pretty new to D3.js library. I've been trying to implement it in React JS project.

I'm just using d3 functions for calculations and rendering part will be done by React JS.

I successfully created a tree but I'm getting **links** with weird style (Not as expected)

This is what I expected (As per [D3 Documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#linkVertical))
[image: Expected Result]

But I got the below tree :(
[image]

Also I can't able to collapse or expand...

You can find the code below.

```
componentDidMount() {
        const width = 800, height = 800;

        const tree = d3.tree().size([height, width - 160]);
        const stratify = d3.stratify().id((d) => {
            return d.name;
        }).parentId((d) => {
            return d.parent;
        });
        const root = stratify(this.state.data)
            .sort((a, b) => {
                return (a.height - b.height) || a.id.localeCompare(b.id);
            });

        this.setState({ paths: tree(root).links() });
        this.setState({ nodes: root.descendants() })
    }

    render() {
        let paths = this.state.paths && this.state.paths.map(item => {
            let d = d3
                .linkHorizontal()
                .x((d) => {
                    return d.y;
                })
                .y((d) => {
                    return d.x;
                });
            return <path className='link' d={d(item)} />
        })
        let nodes = this.state.nodes && this.state.nodes.map((node, i) => {
            return <g key={node.id} className={"node" + node.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"}
                transform={`translate(${node.y}, ${node.x})`}>
                <circle r="10" style={{ 'fill': node.children ? 'lightsteelblue' : 'black' }} />
                <text y="0" dy="0" textAnchor="middle"
                    style={{ 'fillOpacity': 1 }}>{node.name}</text>
            </g>
        })
        return (
            <svg className="tree-chart-basic" ref={(r) => this.chartRf = r} style={{ width: '800px', height: '800px' }}>
                <g transform='translate(20,20)'>
                    {nodes}
                    {paths}
                </g>
            </svg>
        );
    }
```

`this.state.data` will be having the array as follows

```
    [
        { "name": "ProjectA", "parent": "" },
        { "name": "ApplicationA", "parent": "ProjectA" },
        { "name": "EnvironmentB", "parent": "ProjectA" },

        { "name": "TierC", "parent": "ApplicationA" },
        { "name": "TierD", "parent": "ApplicationA" },
        { "name": "TierE", "parent": "ApplicationA" },

        { "name": "ServiceF", "parent": "EnvironmentB" },

        { "name": "ContainerG", "parent": "EnvironmentB" },
        { "name": "ContainerH", "parent": "TierE" },
        { "name": "ContainerH", "parent": "TierE" },
        { "name": "ContainerH", "parent": "TierE" },
        { "name": "ContainerH", "parent": "TierE" },
        { "name": "ContainerH", "parent": "TierE" },
        { "name": "ContainerH", "parent": "TierE" }
    ]
```

1. How can I get the expected Tree in my code?
2. How can I get collapse/expand functionality?

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for the time. (:

Comment: Have you tried using d3.svg.diagonal() ?

Comment: Hi.. I've used `d3.linkVertical()` function which is alternative in latest version. And I'm getting error if I use  `d3.svg..diagonal()`

Comment: Just set `fill: none` for the path elements, then set `stroke` for whatever colour you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the solution to my answer.

I need to specify the style to `<path>` tag as follows.

```
<path
fill="none" 
stroke="#97a6ff" 
strokeWidth="2px" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using [react-tree-graph](https://github.com/jpb12/react-tree-graph) which uses d3 under the hood. Luckily you can add custom classes to customize everything. I use css-modules so I had to *escape* the global classnames.

```
import { Tree } from 'react-tree-graph';
import style from './tree.module.scss';
// ...
<Tree svgProps={{ className: style.acmeProductTree }} />
```

```scss
// tree.module.scss
svg.acmeProductTree path:global(.link) {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #2593b8;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

As I found out just now you can alternatively apply a custom class directly to the `path` element:

```
<Tree pathProps={{ className: style.acmeProductTreeLink }} />
```

```scss
.acmeProductTreeLink {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #2593b8;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```